# Renderer is deprecated as a favor for renderer2, alternative for `invokeElementMethod`?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, renderer

For a side project of mine, I want to implement a chat stream where new message is added to the bottom and the windows should scroll to the bottom to display the latest message.

In order to do that, I have opted to use `ViewChildren` on the component to find the last message(latest) and use `scrollIntoView` on the `nativeElement`.

In order not to call the method by accessing the DOM API directly `nativeElement.scrollIntoView()`. I believe I will need to use `renderer.invokeElementMethod(nativeElement, 'scrollIntoView')`.

Problem is `renderer` is deprecated in favor of `renderer2` and I cant seem to find alternative for the method `invokeElementMethod` in `renderer2`.

Question is, is there a method that I missed in `renderer2` that do just that? or we have a new way doing invoking element method now?

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/15008#issuecomment-285141070

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use **selectRootElement** method of **Renderer2**.

For example:

```
constructor(private renderer: Renderer2) {}

this.renderer.selectRootElement('#domElementId').scrollIntoView()
```

, where **domElementId** is **id='domElementId'** in your html

---

**UPDATE**

> Supply a **Second Argument for selectRootElement** as per [Angular's Official Documentation](https://angular.io/api/core/Renderer2#selectrootelement) as it is **used to preserve your content**
>
> `selectRootElement(selectorOrNode: any, preserveContent?: boolean): any`

```
this.renderer
  .selectRootElement'#domElementId', true)  // Supply true for the 2nd arg to make sure your content is preserved.
  .scrollIntoView()                      // Or ({ behavior: 'smooth' }) for smooth scrolling
```

Comment: I would avoid using `Renderer2` as it's poor documented for unit testing...for testing you'' end up writing your own renderer

Comment: @Drenai this function's prototype has a parameter to preserve content selectRootElement(selectorOrNode: any, preserveContent?: boolean): any

Comment: This may help if you are a <3 of `elementRef` : 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-oi2ydk?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Answer (score 0):

Let's answer this by an exapmple:

In case we have a view like this:

```
<input #inp1 type="text" placeholder="focus on me" />
```

Inside `ngAfterViewInit()`, it needs to be given focused like this:

```
this.renderer.selectRootElement("inp1").scrollIntoView();
```

Comment: @Brian Your inputs are welcome! Can you post the code which worked for you as an answer, so others can benefit?

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-oi2ydk?ctl=1&embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.ts

here is the full example :)